# How to dispose ADODB.Command object in code migrated to VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, adodb

We migrated some obsolete code from VB6 to VB.net and the previous code used ADODB for connecting to oracle. Below is how the code looks like

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

' stored procedures execution here

cmd = Nothing    // I want to dispose this cmd Object
```

`Nothing` worked in VB6 but its creating lot of trouble with .NET there are open cursors on database. I know we should use the latest library and get rid of ADODB but for now is there a way I can dispose this object. I tried `cmd.Dispose()` but that did not worked.

Comment: "I tried cmd.Dispose() but that did not worked.", how it didn't work ? error, exception ?

Comment: there is no Dispose() method exposed by ADODB

Comment: "Latest library"? Do you realize you are over ten years out of date? Just move from ADODB to ADO.NET and you'll find your life a lot easier. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=adodb+ado.net.

Comment: `there is no Dispose() method exposed by ADODB`  so is not a disposable object, whats the problem then?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am not the owner of this application this is code written by someone ages ago I am just trying to help someone here. I know ADO.NET but I dont want to jump into some messy obsolete code

Comment: @vbp: ADODB to ADO.NET is a straightforward conversion

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you for the help. I will move this code to ADO.NET then

Comment: Good. Then you'll just do `Using cmd As New SqlCommand ... End Using`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject.aspx) to tidy up COM objects. ADODDB is a COM library being used through COM Interop.

COM objects being used through COM-Interop will **not** have a `Dispose` method, but may still need to be tidied up manually. Contrast with "proper" .Net objects will likely have a `Dispose` method, or implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net (or C# for that matter), classes which should be disposed should include a `Dispose()` Method. Classes which do not need to be disposed should not include a `Dispose()` method.

In your case, the `Command` instance may not need to be disposed, but I would wager that the `Connection` instance (which you haven't included in your example code, but I'm pretty sure you've got) does.

Comment: COM objects being used through COM-Interop will not have a Dispose method, but may still need to be tidied up manually.